# linux bash script get user input and store in a array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to write a bash script that will get user input and store it in an array.
Input: 1 4 6 9 11 17 22

I want this to be saved as array.

Comment: you don't neeed an array to loop over the values.

Comment: I Dont want to run a dynamic loop. the input will be used in further loops in the code.

Comment: as long as you don't need random access (indexing), there's no reason to use arrays.

Comment: how can i just save it in an array?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

read it like this:

```
read -a arr
```

#### Test:

```
read -a arr <<< "1 4 6 9 11 17 22"
```

print # of elements in array:

```
echo ${#arr[@]}
```

OR loop through the above array

```
for i in ${arr[@]}
do
   echo $i # or do whatever with individual element of the array
done
```

Comment: @anubhava: can u explain why there is an @? Now i get the unexpected token error. I think the for brackets are not balanced

Comment: can you try quotes: `for i in "${arr[@]}"`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32040/discussion-between-anubhava-and-vignesh)

Answer (score 3):

Here's my 2 cents.

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "Enter server names separated by 'space' : " input

for i in ${input[@]}
do
   echo ""
   echo "User entered value :"$i    # or do whatever with individual element of the array
   echo ""
done
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
while read line
do
    my_array=("${my_array[@]}" $line)
done
printf -- 'data%s ' "${my_array[@]}"
```

Hit Ctrl-D to stop entering numbers.

Comment: `my_array+=( $line )` would be much simpler.