# read values from screen into an array

Tags: shell, aix

I want to read entries from my screen input and push them to a array

```
echo "enter the day, example 01 or 02 etc..enter CTRL+D to break";

while read line;
do
    my_array=("${my_array[@]}" $line)
done
```

however when I try to execute it i get the following error

> Syntax error at line 5: `my_array=' not expected.

any inputs what is the syntax error which shell is detecting

P.S : i have run the above snipet in shell as well as bash, error persists
OS: AIX 7.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linux bash script get user input and store in a array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199736/linux-bash-script-get-user-input-and-store-in-a-array)

Comment: Most likely you run the script *from* bash shell, not *via* bash shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this in bash environment as below;

```
user@host:/tmp:>cat testksh.sh 
#!/bin/ksh
echo "enter the day, example 01 or 02 etc..enter CTRL+D to break";
while read line;
do
    my_array=("${my_array[@]}" $line)
done

user@host:/tmp:>./testksh.sh 
    enter the day, example 01 or 02 etc..enter CTRL+D to break
    ./testksh.sh[3]: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 5 : `(' is not expected.

user@host:/tmp:>cat testbash.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the day, example 01 or 02 etc..enter CTRL+D to break";
while read line;
do
    my_array=("${my_array[@]}" $line)
done


user@host:/tmp:>./testbash.sh 
enter the day, example 01 or 02 etc..enter CTRL+D to break
01
```